# divide array contents on newline in perl

Tags: mysql, sql, perl

I want to use contents stored in array line by line.

But I am unable to split it on `'\n'`.
can you guide me on this.

Note that the array contents is coming from select query on `Text` column of SQL table.

```
@somearray="SELECT column from table where condition=something" (column type is "Text")
foreach $line(@somearray)
{
   if($line=~/match-anything-here/) 
   {
       //The match is done on whole array contents and not line by line  
       print $line;
   }
}
```

Comment: AFAIU, you match still a string not an array. You have just one column in SELECT and you got your array from multiple rows. So you iterate over those rows. If this is correct, then show in your code, where you want to split? I see there only matching condition.

Comment: So what is the difficulty to use `@lines = split /\n/, $line`? Try it out and let us know, what exactly went wrong for you.

Comment: @dma - make that into an answer please

Comment: `"SELECT ..."` is a string. Do you mean to say that you are using a DBI module to extract data from an SQL database, and this is a confusing attempt to show what the array contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code might look like:

```
@somearray = <"SELECT column from table where condition=something">

foreach $line (@somearray)
{
   next unless $line =~ /match-anything-here/;

   foreach (split(/\n/, $line))
   {
       print "line: $_; ";
   }
}
```